# ActiveRecord SUM of distinct records that have a child matching a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get the sum of `days_to_complete` for all `training_stages` that have at least one `training_tasks` with `is_complete: => false`. (Note that I'm working in an Engine named `Training`)

```
create_table :training_stages do |t|
  t.references :checklist, index: true
  t.string :name
  t.integer :days_to_complete

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :training_tasks do |t|
  t.references :stage, index: true
  t.string :description
  t.boolean :is_public, default: false, null: false
  t.boolean :is_complete, default: false, null: false

  t.timestamps
end
```

Example Data

```
training_stages:
    id  checklist_id    name    days_to_complete    created_at  updated_at
    1   1   Intake Stage    8   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    2   1   Document State  6   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53

training_tasks:
    id  stage_id    description is_public   is_complete created_at  updated_at
    1   1   Task1   1   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    2   1   Task2   0   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    3   1   Task3   1   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    4   2   Task4   1   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    5   2   Task5   0   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    6   2   Task6   1   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
    7   2   Task7   0   0   2014-11-21 21:03:53 2014-11-21 21:03:53
```

When I run the following, I get 48.

```
# Assume that stages already contains Stage.all
stages.includes(:tasks)
  .where(training_tasks: {is_complete: false})
  .sum(:days_to_complete)
```

It looks like this is returning a stage for each task that matches the condition and then summing them all. So then I tried grouping:

```
stages.includes(:tasks)
  .where(training_tasks: {is_complete: false})
  .group("training_stages.id")
  .sum(:days_to_complete)
```

This actually returns `{1=>24, 2=>24}`

How can I limit the sum to only distinct stages?

Answer (score 0):

In RoR you can do

```
stages.includes(:tasks)
 .where(training_tasks: {is_complete:false})
 .distinct.pluck(:days_to_complete).sum
```

or

```
stages.includes(:tasks)
 .where(training_tasks: {is_complete:false})
 .distinct.to_a.sum(&:days_to_complete)
```